# Why I am getting "unbalanced parenthesis" error in flex

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lexer

I was testing something with lexer, and wrote this regex rule:
`[0-9([a-b])[c-f]] ;`

According [this](https://www.cs.virginia.edu/%7Ecr4bd/flex-manual/Patterns.html) docs, this is equivalent to:
`[0-9a-f()] ;`

> For example, the following character classes are all equivalent:
> [[:alnum:]]
> [[:alpha:][:digit:]]
> [[:alpha:][0-9]]
> [a-zA-Z0-9]

But this is giving me error:

> my_lexer.l:56: unbalanced parenthesis

Surprisingly, this rule won't give the same error!
`[0-9([a-b][c-f]] ;`

Can someone tell where I'm wrong.. I am using win_flex v2.6.4

Comment: The regex is trying to match the first parenthesis "("  for both [0-9([a-b])[c-f]] and [0-9([a-b][c-f]]. But for [0-9([a-b])[c-f]] it then understands that ")" is closing, but cannot recognize the opening parenthesis, giving error unbalanced parenthesis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside a character class, no character has special significance except `\`, `]`, and `-`. (But see below.) So `[0-9([a-b])[c-f]]` starts with the character class `[0-9([a-b]` (digits, letters `a`, and `b` and the symbols `(` and `[`). The next character is an unbalanced close parenthesis , which is an error.

You may have been misled by the syntax of Posix character classes. The sequence `[:` is special inside a character class, but that doesn't apply to a `[` not followed by a `:`.

As indicated in the comments, that misunderstanding is certainly related to a bug in the documentation, which I reported as [issue 521](https://github.com/westes/flex/issues/521).

Comment: >"that doesn't apply to a `[` not followed by a `:`."  But `[[:alpha:][0-9]]` example is given in docs!!

Comment: @sourav: it does say that, but it's wrong. Sorry (on behalf of whoever wrote that )

Comment: sorry not needed :) But can you see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71959436/12357035) question..

Comment: @sourav: I reported this documentation bug (along with another one which is a bit annoying) as [Issue 521](https://github.com/westes/flex/issues/521)